# Is there any way to put the sim card from my cellphone into a hotspot device?

Tags: cellular-internet

Hotspot devices do not have unlimited data. I have unlimited data with sprint (I am aware that they throttle the top 5%). I don't need calling, I just wan't a device that can last a really long time that I can put my sim card from my phone in for my laptop on the go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume you’re referring to devices like Huawei E5330.)

Yes, that’s how they work, after all. You install a SIM card and (ideally) you’re ready to go.

Make sure to check your contract’s conditions. Tethering (which is essentially the same) is sometimes forbidden and they might(!) terminate your contract.